# Is it possible to POST more than one article at once?

Tags: 8

How do I POST two or more articles at once?

Something like follows:

```
{
"_links":{ "type":{ "href":"http://drupal8/rest/type/node/article" } },
"title":[{"value":"Title 1"} ],
"title":[{"value":"Title 2"} ]
}
Result: Status Code: 400 Bad Request "Syntax error"
```

It is even possible for a single request to add more than one article?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is now way to create multiple nodes in one request. You can send multiple requests instead.

The JSON format need not to to be that much complex(as you mentioned in your POST).

You can use the following JSON format to create a node.

> **URL :** http://www.example.com/d8/entity/node
>
> **Method:** POST
>
> **Headers:**
>
> **Name:** X-CSRF-Token
>
> **Value:** TPlhcaO_KESksKPye805T86j0-ja9rhyfaaqi6zpA8

You can get user session token by requesting the following URL

URL: http://www.exmaple.com/rest/session/token

JSON format to create a node  (Article) for **D8**

```
{
  "type":[{"target_id":"article"}],
  "title":[{"value":"Hi World"}],
}
```

I've tested this on my D8 instance. It's working fine. Hope it helps